# Methods defined in an interface can no be used from another class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, interface

I am using Entity Framework 4.1 and code-first approach.

I have the following intefaces

```
namespace BackupCore.Contracts
{
    public interface IEntity
    {
        DbSet getDbSet(BackupCoreContainer context);

        bool isNew() ;
    }
}

namespace BackupCore
{
    interface IDao<IEntity>
    {
        IEntity Save(IEntity ent);

        IQueryable<IEntity> GetAll();

        bool Delete(IEntity ent, out String errMsg);

        void SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

When trying to create an abstract `EntityDao` like this...

```
using BackupCore.Contracts;

namespace BackupCore
{
    public abstract class EntityDao<IEntity> : IDao<IEntity> 
    {
        BackupCoreContainer unique;

        protected BackupCoreContainer Context
        {
            get
            {
                if (unique == null)
                {
                    unique = new BackupCoreContainer();
                }
                return unique;
            }
        }

        IEntity IDao<IEntity>.Save(IEntity ent)
        {
            bool isNew;
            bool success;

            isNew = ent.isNew();


            if (isNew)
            {
                ent.getDbSet(Context).Add(ent);
            }

            //Context.Entry(ent).State = (isNew) ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;

            SaveChanges();
            return ent;
        }
```

I am getting two errors

1. 'IEntity' does not contain a definition for 'isNew' and no extension method 'isNew' accepting a first argument of type 'IEntity' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2. 'IEntity' does not contain a definition for 'getDbSet' and no extension method 'getDbSet' accepting a first argument of type 'IEntity' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I believe I am missing something very basic/obvious here but what is causing this and how can I solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition `public abstract class EntityDao<IEntity> : IDao<IEntity>` defines a type parameter named `IEntity` that *hides* the interface named `IEntity` that you defined elsewhere.

In order to avoid confusion, John (Saunders, in his now-deleted answer) rightly advises using a standard naming convention that eliminates this kind of name conflict: Prefix interface names with `I` and type parameter names with `T`.  This gives

```
public abstract class EntityDao<TEntity> : IDao<TEntity> 
{
    TEntity IDao<TEntity>.Save(TEntity ent)
    {
        bool isNew;
        bool success;

        isNew = ent.isNew();

        if (isNew)
        {
            ent.getDbSet(Context).Add(ent);
        }

        //Context.Entry(ent).State = (isNew) ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;

        SaveChanges();
        return ent;
    }
}
```

You will find that this still does not compile.  Notice how the parameter of the method is no longer `IEntity` but `TEntity`.  The compiler does not yet have any way of knowing that the type argument supplied for `TEntity` will have the members defined on `IEntity`.  The mechanism for informing the compiler of this fact is called "generic type constraints"; that is, you constrain the type parameter to be `IEntity` or a type that implements `IEntity`.  This gives the compiler the guarantee that these members are available.

To apply the constraint, just add a `where` clause to the class declaration:

```
public abstract class EntityDao<TEntity> : IDao<TEntity>
    where TEntity : IEntity
{
    //...
```

It is not necessarily required to make these changes to your definition of `IDao<>`, but, to avoid confusion, it would be a good idea to do so:

```
interface IDao<TEntity>
{
    TEntity Save(TEntity ent);
    IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();
    bool Delete(TEntity ent, out String errMsg);
    void SaveChanges();
}
```

Finally, it is also not necessary to add the type constraint to the type parameter of `IDao<>`, but it is possible.  I prefer to add type constraints only where they are strictly needed by the compiler, but many people would rather add the constraint here because it makes the intent of the code clearer:

```
interface IDao<TEntity> where TEntity : IEntity
{
    TEntity Save(TEntity ent);
    IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();
    bool Delete(TEntity ent, out String errMsg);
    void SaveChanges();
}
```